# Flexbox container not containing items properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently I'm trying to style my flex box so that when the width reduces, the component on the right which in my case is a input form should go under my left component which is some text in my case. But currently when I reduce the size it only contracts the width of both my right and left components even though I have `flex-wrap:wrap` on.

CodeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-sun-73d7u?file=/src/App.tsx

Code:

```
<div className="contact-container" style={{flexDirection:"column",display:"flex",backgroundColor:"#ECECEC"}}>
        <div style={{padding:"20px",display:"flex",justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>
          <div style={{flexDirection:"column", maxWidth:"50%", padding:"20px 60px"}}>
            <p style={{color:"#0E2043",backgroundColor:"#ECECEC", fontSize:"22px",fontWeight:"700", textAlign:"justify"}}>If you are looking to enjoy exactly these benefits, Passport Legacy is here to assist you with your second citizenship. </p>
            <p style={{color:"#0E2043", paddingTop:"30px",backgroundColor:"#ECECEC", textAlign:"justify"}}>If you would like more information about any of the qualifying programs, or our services, please do not hesitate to contact us.</p>
          </div>
          <div style={{maxWidth:"50%",padding:"20px"}}>
        <div style={{padding:"30px"}}>
          <div style={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"column"}}>
          <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <input required className="contactInput" style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
              </div>
            <div style={{display:"flex",flexDirection:"row", flexWrap:"wrap", justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
            <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
            <input required className="contactInput" style={{padding:"5px",width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
            </div>  
            <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
            <input required className="contactInput" style={{padding:"5px",width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="phone"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <input required className="contactInput" style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%"}} type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject"/>
              </div>

              <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <textarea required className="contactInput" style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%"}} rows="4" placeholder="Message" name="message"/>
              </div>
              <div style={{padding:"5px"}}>
              <input required className="contactInput" style={{padding:"5px", width:"100%",color:"white",backgroundColor:"#0E2043"}} type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></input>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
```

Comment: In the codesandbox i cannot see any flex-wrap:wrap  on the flex wrapper of the two columns. If you add that, the right one will go under the left one. Just under `.contact-container` you have a `<div style={{padding:"20px",display:"flex",justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>` add flex-wrap:wrap to this element.

Comment: @MihaiT Yes this worked, but right now in the input tag where I have my 2 input elements(email, phone) are not showing 100% when the screen size is lowered. Anyway I can have those 2 fields fit to the end as well?

Comment: They are not 100% even on big screens. Why are they wrapped inside a div with `flex-flow: row wrap ` ? Do you want them on big screens to be 50/50 and on smaller screens to be 100% ?

Comment: Yes, I want them to be side to side in big screens like so: https://imgur.com/a/K41VD0w and 100% in smaller ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this the solution, i used `grid` instead of `flex` in two places. The first place where two inputs `name` and `email` are wrapped. The second after `.contact-container`. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-architecture-lj6r6?file=/src/App.tsx)